# Get file URL from raw django SQL query

Tags: django, django-3.1

I have two models

```
class Post(models.Model):
   ...

class PostImage(models.Model):
   post = models.ForeignKey(Post)
   ...
```

In a ListView I need to query a post and one image for it, so I end up writing a raw query.
What I hit now is that the url fields are simple path strings which Django tries to
load from my app, instead of the MEDIA_URL which otherwise works if the object is loaded via the ORM.

Is there a way to convert that path to the URL in the template using the Django syntax ?

```
{{ post.image.url }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the [**`.first()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#first) `PostImage` for example and use this to render the image URL:

```
{{ post.postimage_set.first.image.url }}
```

Here `postimage_set` is the default value for the [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), if you specify a `related_name` yourself, then you should replace `postimage_set` with that name.

Comment: If I understand correctly each object of type Post has a refference to models with foreign key the given model which can be accessed using this field `related_name` ?

Comment: @Zarrie: not to an object, since a `ForeignKey` means that each `Post` can have *zero*, *one* or ***more*** `PostImage`s, the `related_name` is the name of a manager to access the related `PostImage`s of a `Post`. So `post.postimage_set` is a manager that manages the collection of related `PostImage` objects. You can for example use `.all()` to access all these objects, or `.first()` and `.last()` to access the first/last related object.